# Differences between "foreign key" and "constraint foreign key"

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I mean for example I can create table like

```
create table XTable
( 
  idt int not null primary key,
  value nvarchar(50),
  idq int,
  constraint fk_idq foreign key(idq) references YTable(idq)
)
```

and I can create it like this

```
create table XTable
(
  idt int not null primary key,
  value nvarchar(50),
  idq int,
  foreign key(idq) references YTable(idq)
)
```

I usually create table like in the second example but now I'm curious about the first example. What is the difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first option is purely for naming the constraint.

From [SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

To allow naming of a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, and for defining a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on multiple columns, use the following SQL syntax

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
  O_Id int NOT NULL,
  OrderNo int NOT NULL,
  P_Id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
  REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

Also, from [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) one can see that `[ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]` is optional.

Comment: Noob question: what benefits does naming the constraint offer?

Comment: @BradTurek Naming a constraint ensures we do not depend on a database introduced naming, which could alter between versions. This provides better consistency when you do periodic database version upgrades, and/or you have a larger team.

Answer (score 27):

The first one assigns a user-defined name to the foreign key, the second one will assign a system-generated name to the foreign key.

User-defined foreign key names can be useful for subsequent statements like these:

```
ALTER TABLE XTable DROP    CONSTRAINT fk_idq;
ALTER TABLE XTable ENABLE  CONSTRAINT fk_idq;
ALTER TABLE XTable DISABLE CONSTRAINT fk_idq;
```

It's harder to alter constraints with system-generated names, as you have to discover those names first.

Comment: So the only use of `CONSTRAINT` is to have an easier way to `DROP`, `ENABLE` or `DISABLE` a constraint? Is it recommended to name *all* constraints?

Comment: @StefanFalk: I would *always* explicitly name all objects in the database as I've only seen regrets when things haven't been done this way, later on when a project goes into maintenance. In fact, it is wise to define a naming scheme where constraints can be visually associated with their tables easily by their name. Looks like a good blog post topic, in fact.

Comment: This makes sense. My naming schema for foreign keys is `fk__referencing_table_name__referenced_table_name` which unfortunately produces quite large names sometimes. :)

Comment: @StefanFalk: I've seen systems where each table had an official, 4-letter abbreviations, such as: **ACCO**UNTS -> ACCO, **AC**COUNT_  **TR**ANSACTIONS -> ACTR, **AC**OUNT_ **T**RANSACTION_ **D**ETAILS -> ACTD. Those abbreviations could then be used for all derived names, such as constraints, indexes, views, aliases (in joins) etc.

Comment: +1 `It's harder to alter constraints with system-generated names, as you have to discover those names first.` ... learned this one the hard way ... For only a listing, try `sp_help 'TableName'`. The generated constraint name will be in the result.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from controlling the name, nothing really. SQL Server will supply a name if you omit it.  FYI, you only need this syntax [(SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d59b2):

```
create table XTable
(
  idt int not null primary key,
  value nvarchar(50),
  idq int references YTable(idq)
)
```

Here's a [fuller example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47811/5/0).