# Difference between ADD FOREIGN KEY and ADD CONSTRAINT fk_foreign_key

Tags: mysql, sql

Does the following in MySQL:

```
alter table TABLE_A 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id (id) REFERENCES TABLE_B(id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

do the same as

```
alter table TABLE_A 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES TABLE_B(id);
```

except that it also adds a BTREE index on the relationship? Or do they complement each other?

Comment: Does the first one really work? Aren't you missing the `foreign key` keyword in there? In that case the difference is only that the first creates a FK with a user-defined name, otherwise MySQL generates a name for the constraint.

Comment: AFAICT they're the same thing; the `CONSTRAINT` clause allows for custom name, otherwise a unique key is picked by MySQL. The term `FOREIGN KEY` *is* required though.

Comment: @Jack In MySQL5 when I don't add FOREIGN KEY it still works though. Does that only count for oracle or something?

Comment: @Michael Not sure, it says so in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) :)

Comment: @Jack thanks i'll put both then to be safe. Put it as an answer i'll click on accept.

Comment: Also: there should be no comma between `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both queries are more or less the same, though according to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) the `FOREIGN KEY` should be present in both queries.

> ```
> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
> [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
> REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
> [ON DELETE reference_option]
> [ON UPDATE reference_option]
> ```

The benefit of `CONSTRAINT [symbol]` is that you can name the constraint rather than MySQL generating the name for you; this symbol must be unique within the database and can be used to later remove the constraint.

Generated symbol names can be seen by checking the table structure after creation:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_A;
```

Answer (score 0):

**CONSTRAINT** syntax is purely for naming purpose, so that you can use that name for implementing the constraint in any other column of the table.

Your [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652629/differences-between-foreign-key-and-constraint-foreign-key) for the question