# Why use named key constraint (Eg: Foreign Key)

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I am not much familiar with the `SQL` and please explain me the difference of following two and what is the best way to use. Is there any advantage using one over a another.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Emp_Id int NOT NULL,
    Dep_Id int NOT NULL,
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (Dep_Id) REFERENCES Department(Dep_Id)
);
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Emp_Id int NOT NULL,
    Dep_Id int NOT NULL,
    ...

    CONSTRAINT fk_EmpDept FOREIGN KEY (Dep_Id) REFERENCES Department(Dep_Id)
);
```

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652629/differences-between-foreign-key-and-constraint-foreign-key - I googled searched "difference between foreign key in create table and constraint foreign key" - always try Google first, you'd be amazed at what you find.

Comment: @Trent- Thanks. Unfortunately I did not find this SO post.

Answer (score 1):

I always name my keys and constraints, generally with enough information that anybody looking at the key name will be able to understand what the key *does*.

- Foreign keys I name `FK_FieldName@TableName`.
- Primary keys I name `PKC_TableName` or `PKN_TableName` ("c" for "clustered" and "n" for "nonclustered", although this is not critical).
- For indexes, I name them based upon their uniqueness, their clusteredness, and an "I" for index, e.g., `UNI_FieldName@TableName`.

The reason for naming is for the convenience both if you ever need to drop the object and, more importantly, if something in your code attempts to violate the relationship / constraint.  It's immediately apparent where the problem is, if you get a message back saying that you've had a key violation of key `FK_FieldName@TableName` but not so clear if the name doesn't make sense.

Comment: 8 years too late, but as a person working with a largely auto-named database, this is the best answer, with additional useful conventions that are great. I appreciate this!

Comment: Thanks, @mochsner ! Really glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is in naming. If you don't explicitly set a name for constraint, it will has auto generated name. For example: FK_*Employee*_Dep_Id__164452B1 . And you'll see this name in description of table keys, in different exceptions and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not name a foreign key, the db implicitly assign a foreign key name for the field.

And if you name a foreign key, the db uses that as foreign key constant name.

You can use `drop  FOREIGN KEY foreign_key_name` for dropping the constraint (for MySql).

You can use `drop  constraint foreign_key_name` for dropping the constraint (for Oracle, MS Sql etc).

You can use

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT foreign_key_name
FOREIGN KEY (field)
REFERENCES foreign_key_table(Foreign_key_field)
```

Answer (score 0):

First example with `FOREIGN KEY (Dep_Id) REFERENCES Department(Dep_Id)` is used in MySQL and it does not allow you to give this constraint specific name.

In the second example with `CONSTRAINT fk_EmpDept FOREIGN KEY (Dep_Id) REFERENCES Department(Dep_Id)` you can change `fk_EmpDept` to basically any name you want.
It can be used in MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, MS Access.

Using second version you can also created Foreign Key constraint on several columns.