# Rails Active Records : foreign_key vs references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys

This is my code

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :posts, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.references :user, type: :uuid
      t.references :user, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true    

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I am confused what is the difference b/w these line.Both lines of code are working fine to accomplish reference between table .

```
t.references :user, type: :uuid
t.references :user, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true   #what this line is doing
```

Can anybody explain me when to use **foreign_key**  or **not** .

I find the similar things while searching these

```
t.references :makers, foreign_key: { to_table: :office }
```

In above code **foreign_key** is not true. It referencing to some table. why is it so.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the document of [references here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-references), it uses same options with [add_reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference).

So, the different is:

`t.references :user, type: :uuid` - Add a column without adding constraint.

`t.references :user, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true` - Add a column and foreign key constraint. If you don't specify `foreign_key`, it will be false.

`foreign_key: { to_table: :table_name }` - It's option to add a column with a custom name instead of convention name.

For example, in document:

`add_reference(:products, :supplier, foreign_key: {to_table: :firms})`

so, it will add a column name `supplier_id` to table `products` and add a foreign key to reference to `firms` table.

If you follow convention name, then you will want to add a column named `firm_id` instead of `supplier_id`.

Answer (score 3):

`foreign_key: true` will create a foreign key constraint, and without it ONLY the foreign key will be created.

to understand the difference between foreign key and foreign key constraint please visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652629/differences-between-foreign-key-and-constraint-foreign-key) link.

specifying `foreign_key: { to_table: :office }`  will make the foreign key reference the `office` table.